# % of cancelled orders to total orders

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need help in deriving new column 'cancellation_percentage' when I have calculated total_orders and cancelled_orders in sub queries.

I am trying below code but its throwing error. Could you please help ?

```
select cancelled_orders,total_orders,cancelled_percentage
CEILING (CAST(cancelled_orders As FLOAT)/CAST(SUM(total_orders) OVER() AS FLOAT)*100)) as cancelled_percentage
from orders;
```

Comment: Start by removing cancelled_percentage from the select line, assuming that is what you are trying to calculate.
Please include the error message in the question body.
Also include the order table definition.
Basically give as much information as possible so that someone else

Answer (score 0):

Missing , after first cancelled_percentage (nb output 2 columns same name?), space between ceiling and ( to many )

```
select cancelled_orders,total_orders,cancelled_percentage,
CEILING(CAST(cancelled_orders As FLOAT)/CAST(SUM(total_orders) OVER() AS FLOAT)*100) as cancelled_percentage
from orders;
```